# I accidentally closed the Raspberry Pi Setup Tool

Tags: display, setup, settings

I accidentally clicked "Cancel" in the Raspberry Pi setup tool that runs on the first boot. How do I get it back? If I can't, which settings do I have to change to make the Raspberry Pi run as it is all setup? (ex. fix display not filling monitor)

Comment: Open an lxterminal and run `piwiz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should still be there, but not autorun.

Try running `/usr/bin/piwiz` in the Run Menu.

It doesn't really do anything that can't be done with `raspi-config`

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the tool you accidentally cancelled is known as `piwiz.desktop` (also known as the "First-run Wizard"), and it is located here: `/etc/xdg/autostart/piwiz.desktop`.

You might first want to check to see if it's still there, and re-start it if you can.

Another alternative is to re-flash your SD card using [`rpi-imager`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-update-to-v1-6/). Follow these instructions, use the "Advanced Options", and select the "Skip first-run wizard" option. That should give you a system that boots as you want - without using the `piwiz.desktop` app.

You will of course need another operational RPi system to install and run `rpi-imager`. If you don't have one, and my first suggestion wasn't available (can't restart `piwiz.desktop`), you may need to start over with a freshly-flashed SD card using the tool you used to flash your card the first time.

Hope that's clear; I've only just learned of this craziness.

Comment: I wish the Raspberry Pi Foundation would at least write an article or add something to their documentation mentioning this, I wonder how many people made this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I remember that you can find the setup wizard on the desktop under the installed applications. Check the menu under "System", "Settings" or similar.